# Time difference: incorrect values of seconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I try to count the time difference between each 2 rows for groupby data by `id`. Data looks like

```
id    date
11    2021-02-04 10:34:46+03:00
11    2021-02-07 14:58:24+03:00
11    2021-02-07 19:23:28+03:00
11    2021-02-08 10:21:44+03:00
11    2021-02-09 11:36:09+03:00
```

I use that:

```
df['time_diff'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].diff().dt.seconds.div(60).fillna(0)
```

I've noticed that my result is incorrect.
And when I use just it

```
df.groupby('id')['date'].diff()
```

I get that and it's correct

```
70225                NaT
72324    3 days 04:23:38
72367    0 days 04:25:04
72515    0 days 14:58:16
73343    1 days 01:14:25
...
```

But when I try to convert it into seconds

```
df.groupby('id')['date'].diff().dt.seconds
```

I get

```
70225         NaN
72324     15818.0
72367     15904.0
72515     53896.0
73343      4465.0
...
```

Why might it happen?

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to answer this without a reproducible example, or an understanding of your *desired* behavior.

I suspect that you can do this with [`pd.Series.dt.total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```py
df.groupby('id')['date'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
```

If that doesn't work, you could try something like:

```
df.groupby('id')['date'].diff() / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
```